# Why '-5<(unsigned)5' is false?

Tags: c

In c programming why I am getting 0 zero for this? Why `-5<(unsigned)5` is  false?

```
main(){  
printf("%d",-5<(unsigned)5);  
getch();  
}
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in your program, at least if you want to print the result of the comparison. As it stands, your code will take a pointer to char ("%d"), subtract 5 (-5), try to compare the resulting pointer with integer 5, and then pass the result (an integer) to `printf` as if it were a pointer. On `gcc` this gives me an warning: `passing argument 1 of 'printf' makes pointer from integer without a cast`. Bottomline: you want to have a comma between the format string and the next argument.

Answer (score 4):

Because it's doing it as an unsigned comparison, which means it's actually checking if `UINT_MAX - 4 < 5`, which obviously is false.

IMO having no unsigned types is one of the few things Java really got right.  It means you don't get headaches like this.

Comment: but i m also getting false when i type -5<unsigned(6)

Comment: @tyt: Yeah, considering that `UINT_MAX` is over 4 billion, (assuming 32 bits as the default int size for your system,) that's to be expected.

Comment: "IMO having no unsigned types is one of the few things Java really got right. It means you don't get headaches like this." . Seems like throwing the baby out with the bath water to me. Just because the designers of C couldn't be bothered defining sane comparisions between signed and unsigned types doesn't mean it can't be done.

Comment: Well there are two different models (I'll call them modular and positive) and you need two types. C choose one (modular -- unsigned was introduced because people abused less restrictive rules and pointer arithmetic to get that behavior) and it is a pain when you want the other one.  Ada choose the other and ended up by adding modular types to gather for the cases where the C choice is desirable.